# installing ubuntu on windows xp

Tags: installation, 12.10, live-usb

I want to put ubuntu 12.10 on a Sandisk Cruzer 4gb USB flash drive, and then plug in the flash drive to my dell dimension 3000 so I can boot off the flash drive and install ubuntu.     How do I do this? Help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have a dell dimension 3000 as well and here's how I did mine, I downloaded the ISO an then downloaded pen drive linux I chose the ISO on pen drive linux and said that it was ubuntu 12.10 then I told it to write it to the usb directory.  Once it was done I restarted my pc and when it says dell press f12 and then boot from usb.  Afterwards once its booted click install and then follow the prompts from there.

I hope this helped.